# Request path is not working properly in Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, html, laravel

I'm trying to use the following if condition to show something only if the current page is 'results.blade.php' :

```
@if(Request::path() === 'results')
    <p> results page </p>
@else
     <p> Other page </p>
@endif
```

The following is the results path :

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\sharp\resources\views
```

The output is always "Other page" , even if the opened page was 'results' page.

The following is the route :

```
Route::get('/search', [
    'uses' => 'SearchController@getResults',
    'as' => 'results'
]);
```

Comment: can you show your route?

Comment: Added the route

Comment: why are you using `===` instead of `==`

Comment: @farooq , both not working.

Comment: @AbdallahSakre what is inside your controller? . Post the `SearchController@getResults` code. How you redirecting from controller to view?

Comment: It is working fine for me .  Tested now . I'm getting results only

Comment: Have you tried to actually output your `Request::path()` to see what it contains (`{{ Request::path() }}`)? Does it return "results"? Given your route it should be "search". https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/requests#basic-request-information

Comment: @AbdallahSakre I have posted answer, please try, Error occurs because of `/`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're confusing the url/path part with the name of the route. Change your code to

```
@if(Request::path() === 'search')
    <p> results page </p>
@else
     <p> Other page </p>
@endif
```

and everything should work as expected.

From the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/requests#basic-request-information):

> "*The path method returns the request's URI.*"

The URI part of your route is "`/search`" (which could also be written as `search`). The *name* of that route is "`results`" which is used to reference that URI: `return route('results');` will output "http://localhost:8000/search"

Edit: Routes with parameters:

If you have a route

```
Route::get('/user/{uid}', [
    'uses' => 'UserController@show',
    'as' => 'userprofile'
]);
```

you can check for a specific user route (`http://localhost/user/3`) using:

```
@if ( Request::path() == 'user/3')
<p>User Profile 3</p>
@else
<p>NOT User Profile 3</p>
@endif
```

If you want to check any user route (`http://localhost/user/1`, `http://localhost/user/2` ...) use the *name* of the route:

```
@if ( Request::route()->getName() == 'userprofile')
<p>User Profile</p>
@else
<p>NOT User Profile</p>
@endif
```

Comment: What if the URI holds a variable:  Route::get('/user/{us_id}',

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: How will this {us_id} be added in the request::path() ==='user'

Comment: Depends on the URL you are calling: if you are on `http://localhost:8000/user/3` `Request::path()` will return `user/3` - it's the URL path.

Comment: Syntax in blade will include the id part ?

Comment: I edited my answer to include routes with parameters, hope this helps. If it did and solved your question please accept it

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

So I tested your code in my `laravel` project . And for me it is working fine . 
You forgot to post your `SearchController` code here .

The problem is you are mentioning the route using two different names . You should use the same name in `get('/search')` and in `'as'=>'search'` ,

in my `web.php` file,

```
Route::get('/search', [
    'uses' => 'SearchController@getResults',
    'as' => 'search'
]);
```

In my `SearchController` I just redirecting the route to view file .

```
public function getResults() {
    return view('results');

}
```

and in my `results.blade.php` , I used the same code as yours :

```
@if(Request::path() === 'search')
    <p> search page </p>
@else
     <p> Other page </p>
@endif
```

I hope this will be helpful  .

Comment: "_The problem is you are mentioning the route using two different names . You should use the same name in get('/search') and in 'as'=>'search'_" Actually no, `/search` is the url, `results` is the (internal) name you can use to reference the url

Comment: What if the URI holds a variable such as Route::get('/user/{us_id}